# How to disable Hasura schema introspection?

Tags: graphql, schema, hasura

I am going to publish my app in production. Currently, I am trying to disable the database schema introspection in Hasura core. I tried to download the metadata and add the following to the file

```
"graphql_schema_introspection": {
      "disabled_for_roles": [
        "user"
      ]
    }
```

It doesn't work. But I try in Hasura cloud, it's worked. Maybe this feature is only in Hasura cloud, not Hasura core.

Is there any alternative way to disable the schema introspection in Hasura core?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to activate AllowList and introspection queries automatically becomes not allowed query.

You will need to add introspection queries into AllowList to enable them.

Notes:

- you can't disallow introspection for `admin` role. That's reasonable:  applications must not work in `admin` role anyway.
- you can't allow for one role and disallow for another: allow lists are not defined per role

Comment: If AllowList is enabled, we'll need to specify the list of queries, mutations & subscriptions that we have used in our client. The method would act like disabling query introspection, but at the same time, you will not be able to use any queries that are not specified in the list for any roles except the admin.